# python - copy columns from one file to another

Tags: python, copy

I need some help because I am just a novice in python.
I want to copy some columns from one file to another. But I've only managed to copy the whole file.
My code is the following:

```
    with open('pb_rt_copy.txt','w') as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include an example of your text file.
I assume your columns will have a separator, e.g. a comma or space. You can split the line using the separator `line.split(',')` which returns a list of your line entries. Then grab the one you want and write only that to the new file.

Comment: The file is separated by space. How would I use line.split? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your file has columns separated by spaces and you would want to copy column number 3. Then you could do something like this:

```
col_idx = 2  # third column
with open('pb_rt_copy.txt','w') as f1:
    for line in f:
        col_text = line.split(' ')[col_idx]
        f1.write(col_text)
```

Comment: This works fine to copy just one column and in the new file I get the data as a row instead of a column. How would I do to copy more than one column and keep them as columns? Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can use the code provided and adapt it to the case of multiple columns very easily (just add another `col_text2 = line.split(' ')[col_idx2]`). To create a new line add `'\n'`. If this is not clear yet, I would advise you to google for a tutorial on python strings and learn the fundamentals first. Stackoverflow can help you solving programming issues. But the purpose is not providing exact implementations to a person problem. You are required to write your own code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask